# Position button on top-end of CardView

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, materialcardview

[image]

How can I add a button on top-end of CardView?
I have a solution but I don't like set a fixed height (ie 50dp) of button and than set margin_top (ie 25dp) of card_view.
Do you have other solutions?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/corner_radius"
    app:cardElevation="2dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/btn">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view_cover"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="#ddd"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="16:9"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    android:id="@+id/btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dimen_16"
    android:elevation="@dimen/dimen_2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Does the inserted picture represent precisely what you're aiming for?

Comment: Yes, with my code I can obtain the same result as image but I am using a fixed "dp" of button and I don't like this. I want know if there are other better solutions using only constraint

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".fragments.LibraryFragment">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/my_card"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="16:9"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        />


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_delete"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.08"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:tint="@color/redColor"
        android:elevation="50dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/my_card"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/my_card"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/my_card"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/my_card"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.98"
        />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This will generate output like this
[image]

the image size will be based on the width of the screen which will be differ from device to device and it will resize according to it. and also it will be square due to we provided the ratio as 1:1

Comment: Yes, this is a good solution. The solution so is NOT set app:layout_constraintTop_toTop but set on bottom.

If in the card_view we use `app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"`, how can I set the button in the middle of card_view border? Because, as  you know, the compatpadding generate a little padding of the card.   https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImmyG.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Looks like constraint layout doesn't allow negative margin(offset), so all you can do is workarounds.

There is another workaround, which i think is better than your example in terms of "intention". It goes like this:

Assuming your button is `50dp` width/height.

1. Place `Space` element inside the constraint layout. Let's say width/height is `25dp`(half of `50dp`).
2. Align the `Space` element to the corner of the constraint layout. In case you want to put the button top end, then top of `Space` to top of constraint layout, and end of `Space` to end of constraint layout.

At this point, you virtually created "anchor" points where you can align other elements to, that is, the bottom and start of `Space`.

3. Align the start of the button to the start of `Space`, and the bottom of the button to the bottom of `Space`.

The button is now placed as if you would do `layout_marginEnd`/`layout_marginBottom` of `-25dp`.

The reason I think this is better is that the overlapping detail is no longer the constraint layout's concern, instead, it's the button and its neighboring element's.

Comment: Personally, if this layout is a one-time thing, I would put it this way. If it's a repeated theme, I would put it into a template and include it with a specific width/height of the button and width/height of the offset for each use case.

Comment: But you are using a fixed height of button 50dp.
I am not using negative margin/padding...I only set margin_top 25dp (half of 50dp)
but I prefert doesn't set 50dp as height.

I am trying Guideline, but without good results

Comment: My point is that the child button being in that position is not parent(constraint layout)'s concern. It's about the position of the button **relative to the CardView**, where you would want to say "negative 25dp from end/top of CardView". But it seems that this negative margin isn't directly possible on android framework.